# Request array to another class

Tags: c#, arrays, class, request

I want to request array from class and use it in program. `:base` dont work

This is my `RandomArray` Class

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
public class RandomArray

{

    /// <summary>
    /// create a single random number generator
    /// </summary>
    static readonly Random generator = new Random();
    /// <summary>
    /// here are the random numbers stored
    /// </summary>
    int[] array;
    /// <summary>
    /// store the min, max used to generate the data
    /// </summary>
    readonly int min, max;
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor only needs how the value limits
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="min">The minimum value (typical 0)</param>
    /// <param name="max">The maximum value (example 100)</param>
    public RandomArray(int min, int max)
    {
        this.min=min;
        this.max=max;
        this.array=new int[0];
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Fills the array with random numbers
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="count">The number of data to generate</param>
    public void Fill(int count)
    {
        this.array=new int[count];
        // fill array with random integers
        for (int i=0; i<array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i]=generator.Next(min, max);
        }
    }        
    /// <summary>
    /// Copy constructor if needed (optional)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="other">A RandomArray to copy the data from</param> 
    public RandomArray(RandomArray other)
    {
        this.min=other.min;
        this.max=other.max;
        this.array=(int[])other.array.Clone();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Provide the data
    /// </summary>

    public int[] Array { get { return array; } }
    /// <summary>
    /// Provide the limits used
    /// </summary>

    public int Min { get { return min; } }
    public int Max { get { return max; } }
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a comma separated list of numbers like <c>[45,32,64,..]</c>
    /// </summary>
    public string ToStringList()
    {
        string[] parts=new string[array.Length];
        for (int i=0; i<parts.Length; i++)
        {
            parts[i]=array[i].ToString();
        }
        return "["+string.Join(",", parts)+"]";
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Shows only the limits used
    /// </summary>
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("RandomArray({0},{1})", min, max);
    }
}

<!-- language: none -->
```

I want to sort this array, so i create another Class: BubbleSort.

```
<!-- language: c#-->
class BubbleSort : RandomArray // inherit from RandomArray Class
    {

        public void Bubble() 
        {
            int temp;

            for (int j = 1; j <= Array.Length - 2; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= Array.Length - 2; i++)
                {
                    if (Array[i] > Array[i + 1])
                    {
                        temp = Array[i + 1];
                        Array[i + 1] = Array[i];
                        Array[i] = temp;
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }
}
<!-- language: none -->
```

And the last thing is button:

```
<!-- language: c#-->

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {

            BubbleSort p = new BubbleSort();
            p.Bubble();
        }
<!-- language: none -->
```

How can I operate (sort) on this same array? Now i have error: `'MyProgram' does not contain a constructor that takies 0 arguments.`
Please help, regards :)

Comment: IF you need to sort an array , you can use a SortedList or a Generic List<> , Easily sortable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message is telling you, your `RandomArray` class only has a single constructor which accepts **two parameters**: `RandomArray(int min, int max)`. This means that your derived class' constructor must **also** pass these parameters to the base class' contructor.

```
class BubbleSort : RandomArray 
{
     public BubbleSort(int min, int max)
         : base(min, max)
     { }
}
```

You can also have a different constructor overload which passes default parameters:

```
class BubbleSort : RandomArray 
{
     public BubbleSort(int min, int max)
         : base(min, max)
     { }

     public BubbleSort()
         : this(1, 10) 
     { }
}
```

What's more important, however, is that inheritance is the **wrong approach** here: "Bubble sort" is **not** an array. "Bubble sort" is a "sorting algorithm".

In other words, if anything, you could write something like:

```
interface ISortAlgorithm<T>
{
     void Sort(T[] array);
}
```

And then define `BubbleSort` as:

```
class BubbleSort : ISortAlgorithm<int>
{
     public void Sort(int[] array) 
     { 
         ...
     }
}
```

Comment: Non generic type 'MyProgram.ISortAlgorithm' cannot be used with this type arguments

Comment: @user2971920: are you sure that you typed the `interface` declaration correctly? I.e. `interface ISortAlgorithm<T>`? That "`<T>`" part is important to make it generic.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. It's working, but don't show the result in textbox. I add Interface but on textbox i have `MyProgra.BubbleSort` instead of numbers.
It's my code in button `BubbleSort p = new BubbleSort();
            textBox1.Text = p.ToString();`

I must override this method ?

Comment: @user2971920: The `ToString` method itself does nothing much (except return the class name by default), unless explicitly overridden. Also, you need to specify how you want to display your data. And `TextBox` does not seem like an ideal control to display a list of numbers. It would be best that you post a new question on StackOverflow with a detailed description.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

problem here is Random function missing constructor with zero argument

```
public class RandomArray
{
   public RandomArray()
   {}
}
```

i think you forget to call function , you can come out of the error like this

```
 public void Bubble() :base()
 {
```

Option 2:

or to avoide error with existing code

```
 public void Bubble() :base(1,10)
 {
```

Option 3:

or you can modify you child class constructor like this

```
 public void Bubble(int i) :base(i)
 {
```

Comment: When i use :base all my class is broke. There are errors like 'invalid token' and 'syntax error'.

Comment: @user2971920 - it might be because of extra space

Comment: I don't understand this, if I type :base all my class is broking. After BubbleSort() i write :base and my class is full of red colors by errors.

Answer (score 0):

i would include the sort method into your arrayclass if you already made one:

```
public void Bubble() 
{
    int temp;

    for (int j = 1; j <= array.Length - 2; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= array.Length - 2; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] > array[i + 1])
            {
                temp = array[i + 1];
                array[i + 1] = array[i];
                array[i] = temp;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
RandomArray myArray = new RandomArray(0,5);
myArray.Bubble();
```